# Python getting IDE linter to see from System imports within pythonnet's clr

Tags: python, pycharm, ide, clr, python.net

I am using the `pythonnet` package in MSMQ communications.  In my IDE (PyCharm CE), I have the following sample code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3 

import pythoncom 
import clr

  clr.AddReference("System") 
clr.AddReference("System.Messaging") 
from System import TimeSpan
 from System.Messaging import MessageQueue
```

Aside: this code works fine when I actually run it using Python `3.6`.

And below is a screenshot of what it looks like inside PyCharm.

[image: What I Am Seeing]

- For `System` it says: `Unresolved reference 'System'`

Other than using `noqa` comments, **how can I get my PyCharm linting to do the following**:

- Not complain about `from System import XYZ`?

---

**Versioning Info**

- IDE: PyCharm Community Edition `2019.2`
- pythonnet `2.3.0`, installed in a virtual environment

Comment: Hi. Are you 100% sure your Virtual Environment is enabled? (You can confirm it in right part of your status bar). In a terminal, inside PyCharm, what gives pip3 freeze output?

Comment: Hi @Bsquareℬℬ, yeah my venv is configured correctly. I confirmed I have `pythonnet==2.3.0` both via Settings --> Project Interpreter and via Pycharm terminal `pip freeze` as you suggested

Comment: Could you give your complete output of pip3 freeze (pip3 is important, otherwise you may use the Python2 version which is NOT what you want).

Comment: Hi @Bsquareℬℬ thanks for getting back to me again.  On my machine, `pip -V` outputs `python 3.6`.  On my machine, I have installed a large `requirements.txt`, so outputting a full `pip3 freeze` is not super useful, in my opinion.  Just to be sure, I checked that `pip3 freeze` outputs `pythonnet`.  Is there something in specific you had been thinking?

Comment: Are you using virtual environment? Are you 100% sure pythonnet building was OK and well installed?

Comment: Hi @Bsquareℬℬ, I just updated the question and wording.  I decided to completely delete my `venv` and reinstall, since you made me uncertain.  And voila, it no longer complains about the `clr` import.  PyCharm now "sees" `clr`.  I am wondering, do you know of a way to fix linting on the `from System` imports?

Comment: Hey, very nice! Do you wan't to disable only linting issue on these specific imports, or on all kind of "unresolved reference"?

Comment: I've found how to do it the proper way, I'm going to create a complete clean answer to save the solution ;)

Comment: Okay, yeah @Bsquareℬℬ, see my comment on your answer.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my complete answer, according to our exchanges.

## Issue #1

> No module named clr

After some checks, it seems there was a kind of mix between the operating system environment, and your project's virtual environment.

Solution: delete and re-create properly virtual environment fixed it

---

## Issue #2

> Unresolved reference 'System'

In this case where corresponding modules are loaded dynamically, your best solution is to disable PyCharm's Inspector on these specific lines; thus you won't loose anything else in your IDE.

You can see [How to disable inspection](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html).

In my sandbox, I just had to:

- go on corresponding source code lines with warning (one after the other)
- use the `More actions` context menu on the error (`System` in this case)
- use the `Ignore unresolved reference 'pythonnet_tests.System'` sub-menu
- use finally the `Suppress for statement`

Each time the corresponding source code line, will be preceded by a comment line:

`# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences`

And that's it!

Comment: Okay so to circle back, basically, there's no way to get IDE to properly "see" the imports like `from System import TimeSpan`, so we just suppress the inspection locally.  I think this makes sense.  Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Yes I agree with this conclusion.